# Is there a way to use xpath to search for a value where a part of the value dynamically changes?

Tags: xpath

I’m trying to match a value where I don’t necessarily know the whole value every time i.e. it's randomly generated. Is there a way to search for a value where a part of the value dynamically changes?

Please see my example of value I'm trying to find and my attempted xPath:

```
<div class="target" testid="target”>
<h2>Hi, random user</h2>
<p>To get the xpath <b>target</b> of <b>[text I don’t know]</b> in <b>[text I don’t know]</b>, you need to do the following</p>
</div>
```

I’ve tried the following xpath I picked up from another question but it don’t get a match:

```
//p[matches(.,'^To get the xpath <b>target</b> of <b>.*</b> in <b>.*</b>, you need to do the following$')]
```

I’ve tried different combinations with and without the bold tag but can’t seem to get it to match. truthfully I'm not sure I've got the right syntax...

Comment: The `matches` function works on strings not on nodes so unless you have escaped markup it doesn't make any sense that your second argument says e.g `<b>target</b>` as the attempt to use `//p[matches(., '...')]` means the `matches` function processes the plain text content of the `p` element node, e.g. `To get the xpath target of .*? in .*?, you need to...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the plain text in the second argument of `matches` e.g.

```
//p[matches(., '^To get the xpath target of .*? in .*?, you need to do the following$')]
```

Online sample [here](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xpath31fiddle/?xpath=%2F%2Fp%5Bmatches%28.%2C%20%27%5ETo%20get%20the%20xpath%20target%20of%20.*%3F%20in%20.*%3F%2C%20you%20need%20to%20do%20the%20following%24%27%29%5D&input=%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22target%22%20testid%3D%22target%22%3E%0D%0A%3Ch2%3EHi%2C%20random%20user%3C%2Fh2%3E%0D%0A%3Cp%3ETo%20get%20the%20xpath%20%3Cb%3Etarget%3C%2Fb%3E%20of%20%3Cb%3E%5Btext%20I%20don%E2%80%99t%20know%5D%3C%2Fb%3E%20in%20%3Cb%3E%5Btext%20I%20don%E2%80%99t%20know%5D%3C%2Fb%3E%2C%20you%20need%20to%20do%20the%20following%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E&input-type=XML).

Comment: In terms of pure XPath this answers my question as it is worded, thank you. However, it does not address my issue, as I understand my current framework, I do not have XPath 2.0.

Comment: @saab613, I am sorry, as your question shows the use of `matches` and regular expression I thought you would be using XPath 2. I can't fix an error in the use of `matches` if you later tell me your environment doesn't support `matches`.

Comment: I agree and my information was not correct. As i was unaware until VERY recently that it wasn't Xpath2.0. As I said, in terms of pure Xpath and using the matches term, you are correct and thus my upvote and acceptance of your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use `contains()` method using the fixed attribute value?
Something like:

```
//p[contains(.,'you need to do the following')]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to assert the whole value... this is just an example text to get an idea of the issue I'm trying to solve, an individual part on either side of the 'random texts' would not be unique enough.

Comment: I don't understand. If the text is random - how can you assert unknown random value? On the other hand if you do know at least part of the text you can locate that element, extract it entire text and then do with it what you want.

Comment: Apologies, I'm probably not making much sense... For context, I'm using it as part of selenium c# to assert something exists. The text will have some unique parts known, but it will follow a pattern, I'm interested in asserting the pattern is followed. e.g. the random text will be a GUID encapsulated in a string of text, I need to assert the format of the string is correct rather than know the GUID, which I'll never know before this point. The String will have other unique identifiers that I know how to grab, I just don't seem to know the syntax to ignore a GUID... Hope this makes more sense.

Comment: So you're using a version of selenium that supports the XPath 2.0 function `matches()`?

Comment: Maybe I still do not understand you, but as I understand: the text will contain some known, unique text. Right? If so you can locate that element based on that known, unique text as I mentioned in my solution. Once you located the element you can extract ALL it text content. Then you can do whatever you need with that text, assert its content, format etc.